# Zabbix 6 agent: failed to initialize builtin counter

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, zabbix, system-monitoring, disk-monitoring

I am doing a zabbix 6 installation and configuration of a Windows machine, after installing and configuring the zabbix agent, everything seems to work fine. But after a few hours everything fails and the light turns red, I check the zabbix_agentd.log on the windows machine and I see the following error:

> 3144:20230824:115158.477 **** Enabled features ****
> 3144:20230824:115158.478 IPv6 support: YES
> 3144:20230824:115158.479 TLS support: YES
> 3144:20230824:115158.480 **************************
> 3144:20230824:115158.481 using configuration file: C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.conf
> 3144:20230824:115159.012 Failed to initialize builtin counter: % Processor Time
> 3144:20230824:115159.013 Failed to initialize builtin counter: Total
> Sessions
>
> 4108:20230824:115253.910 Unhandled exception c0000005 detected at
> 0x00007FFE7C864EAB. Crashing ...

What might be the problem? How could it be solved?